# Why is the "winner" function of my game code not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to create a dice game using Javascript and everything works except the "winner" function.

The goal is to get the game to reset at 20 points, although when the game goes above 20 nothing happens, and I don't know why. I'm new to coding so I would really appreciate a solid explanation as to why this is the case.

```
let player1Score = 0
let player2Score = 0
let player1Turn = true

const player1Dice = document.getElementById("player1Dice")
const player2Dice = document.getElementById("player2Dice")
const player1Scoreboard = document.getElementById("player1Scoreboard")
const player2Scoreboard = document.getElementById("player2Scoreboard")
const message = document.getElementById("message")
const rollBtn = document.getElementById("rollBtn").addEventListener("click", rollDice)
const resetBtn = document.getElementById("resetBtn")



roll dice, html, and css editor

function rollDice(){
    
   let diceRoll = Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1;
     if (player1Turn) {
             player1Score += diceRoll;
             player1Dice.textContent = diceRoll;
             player1Scoreboard.textContent = player1Score;
             message.innerText = "player 1 turn";
             player1Dice.classList.remove("active");
             player2Dice.classList.add("active");
     } else {
            player2Score += diceRoll;
            player2Dice.textContent = diceRoll;
            player2Scoreboard.textContent = player2Score;
            message.innerText = "player 2 turn";
            player2Dice.classList.remove("active");     
            player1Dice.classList.add("active");
    }

    switch turn element

             player1Turn = !player1Turn
     }

    player x has won element

    if (player1Score >= 20) {
             message.textContent = "Player 1 has won! "
              winner()
             
    } else if (player2Score >= 20) {
             message.textContent = "Player 2 has won! "
             winner()
    }

    function winner(){
            rollBtn.style.display = "none"
            resetBtn.style.display = "block"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a [tour] of the site, read [ask], and consider updating your question with a [mre] of your code so that we can test it and see what errors are occurring.

Comment: Also, consider running your code through a JS validation site such as https://beautifytools.com/javascript-validator.php which may produce error messages for you to track back to your project file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an issue when you initialise the variable `rollBtn`,
you are actually calling the `addEventListener` method after getting `document.getElementById`. Basically, in the variable `rollBtn`, you are not storing the HTML element; you are just storing what the eventListener returns.

You can fix it quickly:

```
const rollBtn = document.getElementById("rollBtn")
rollBtn.addEventListener("click", rollDice)
```